# Cloudflare NS outage and having non Cloudflare NS3?

Tags: nameservers, cloudflare

Due to rising server load from DOS attacks I've decided to use Cloudflare, but I am aware their users suffered an hours outage in March because all Cloudflare Name Servers were "down".

I have my own NS, can I retain this as NS3 for the domain (for fallback) alongside Cloudflares "NS1 & NS2"?

What would the impact be?

I am aware Nameservers aren't selected in number order but I believe it is likely that Cloudflares commonly used NS in the client's locale are likely to be selected first - so only a small portion of traffic would use my NS3 (without the benefits of Cloudflare services). Is this correct or just wishfull thinking on my part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do consider opening a support ticket for these kind of questions at CloudFlare directly.

You won't be able to leave additional name servers in place, as in ns3 and n4 -- in addition to the 2 provided CloudFlare name servers. To use our service you'd need to only have our 2 name servers in place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't contact Cloudflare directly because I wanted an independent view on the pros and cons (if possible). But as you point out I see this is not possible.  I have just found a single article covering this issue, which like you say states that Cloudflare doesn't allow this and disables their service. The article points out this makes Cloudflare a single point of failure, and is something that Cloudflare should reconsider. [link]http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2013/03/15/cloudflare-now-offering-to-be-your-single-point-of-failure/[/link]

Comment: whoops link has link stuck on end. Correct link: http://themattreid.com/wordpress/2013/03/15/cloudflare-now-offering-to-be-your-single-point-of-failure/

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, 33% of traffic will be served by your NS.

You can TCP/UDP stream proxy with n* nginx/haproxy/dnsmasq to n* NS backend to load balance incoming requests.

I tested several dnsmasq scenarios, you can serve 15k r/s with a simple Celeron up to 150k r/s with redundant, cheap, geo distributed VPSes. You can also use AWS Route53 to have solid perfs.

In addition to that you can spin up n* nginx proxy manager instances with WAF enabled and SSL wildcard certificates to match most of the "Cloudflare edge logic" and protect/mask your origin ip addresses even if 1/3rd of the clients resolves origins from your own NS.